# Проверка состояния ADQuery

Tags: delphi

Есть ADQuery. Как проверить, находится ли ADQuery в режиме редактирования?
Я пробовал так:

```
  if uData.ADQMain.State = dsEdit then
  begin
    // тут код какой то
  end;
```

Но при компиляции возникает ошибка...

> dsEdit - неизвестный тип.

Как же проверить, находится ли ADQuery в режиме редактирования?

Answer (score 1):

Если ADQuery потомок от `TDataSet` то свойство `State` имеет тип `TDataSetState`, и тогда проверка выглядит так:

```
if uData.ADQMain.State in [dsEdit, dsInsert] then ...
```

Посмотрите тип вашего `State`. Или посмотрите есть ли в `uses` модуль `DB`. Именно в нем объявлен тип `TDataSetState`.